# How do I enable the nudity filter?

Tags: rust

I want to disable nudity by adding the pixelated filter I see in youtube videos like this one (seen best at 1m16s and 1m34s):

How do I do that?

Comment: Could you possibly link to an example video?

Comment: [Edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/295232/edit) your question, rather than posting that in a comment.

Comment: Are you asking about seeing the nudity in the game, or in the video? One belongs on out site, one does not.

Comment: In the game of course.

Comment: You want to disable the nudity filter, or disable nudity?  You said both, and those are opposite goals

Comment: I want to disable the nudity

Comment: Also it was a 5 seconds.

Comment: The 0m5s example is really brief, so we couldn't see what you meant. The 1m16s example is long enough to really see it, and has another example shortly after, so it's a good spot to link to in the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a console command for it.

From this [Steam post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/252490/discussions/0/630799997157076422/):

> open console in game with F1 and type censor.nudity true

**Edit:** I was watching a [Markiplier Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXGPlpsCAGk) and there's a point where he goes into the options to turn off censorship.  It looks like to get to the censorship option you go into your Settings, select Options, and then toggle the censor nudity option at the bottom (the video was recorded using version Alpha Win.1107.85 - it may look slightly different depending on what version of the game you are on).  You can see it around the 9:30 mark.